# Input to Pi 4 with only mouse

Tags: pi-4

Can you Input to Pi 4 with only  mouse?
I have tried a lot of the input methods but none of them seem to work.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve ... it appears that your question is not really the actual question

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible to attach only a mouse to the Pi (or only a touchscreen). But since Linux is not really optimized for that, you'll have to use an On-Screen keyboard quite often, which is quite nasty for a command line interface. However, if you're only using software that is designed for mouse interaction, that will work as with any other computer.